# Setting Up NetSuite IDE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, suitescript, suitecloud

I'm trying to start using the Eclipse IDE for NetSuite SDF, but every time I try to upload or download (or do anything) a script, I'm receiving an error of "javax/xml/soap/SOAPException".

Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) - Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers(I've also tried Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers with the same issue)

I've tried creating a new SuiteScript Project (type 1.0 to start with) called TestScript. I've then created a sample workflow action script.

I've tried connecting to both production and sandbox. Using the Non-2FA Developer role as suggested by SuiteAnswers (70304). I've re-installed Eclipse and the IDE framework (2019.1).

My script looks like:

`function sampleFunction(){
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Sample', 'Hello world');
}`

I'd expect to load this to the file cabinet under SuiteScripts/TestScript, but I'm receiving that SOAPException error instead. I've also tried setting up a TBA authentication for the user, but I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this problem on machines with java installed through `brew cask`. I offer a poor solution, but one that worked for us:

1. Make sure you have JDK 1.8 installed, and find where it is installed;
2. Close Eclipse.
3. Edit your `eclipse.ini` file (which we found at `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini` on our macs)
    Enter the following (changed for wherever you found your jdk 1.8 installation) above the existing `-vmargs` line:

   ```
   -vm
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
   ```

   (That's `-vm` on one line, the path on the next line, the existing `-vmargs` line below that.)
4. Restart Eclipse & try again.

Limitations of this solution:
I doubt this updated version of the `.ini` file will survive Eclipse updates. It'd be great if there was (and there probably is) an `.ini` file location in the user dir that overrode this one.
Updates to the JDK installation will require manual changes to the `.ini` file.

… but, it works!

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot. I found success using Webstorm instead so I'm giving that a try now, but I've always used Eclipse so I'm not sure if I'm ready to make the full leap to WS. I'll follow up once I've tried this out.

Comment: to check your JDK version, this SO question seems helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363446/how-to-know-the-jdk-version-on-my-machine