# How to know the jdk version on my machine?

Tags: java, java-8

I have recently uninstalled JDK 11 and installed JDK 8. For confirmation, I want to check which JDK is installed on my Windows 10 machine. I typed `java -version` on cmd then get the error message

> java is not recognized as an internal or external command

How to know which JDK version installed on my PC?

Comment: First uninstall all the versions of Java, install Jdk 8. Open new command prompt and  type java -version.

Comment: If your JDK is on your path you should be able to tell by just running 'javac -version'. From the error you described it sounds like you're on Windows, so if the first command fails try executing (with the quotes) the following: "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac -version"

Comment: @AlexBroadwin your method worked for me. But i've installed 8th version and in cmd "1.8.0_221" is coming. What does that mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you might need to add `path` in environment variables which you can find in **Control Panel**
open the **Jdk** where you installed and add until `/bin` in the path in environment variables.

Add until `/bin` in path variable in **System Variables** which is residing in **Environment Variables**.

Then do 
`java -version`
 which might show up.

If still problem persists, try restarting your pc and see.

Comment: Your method worked for me. But i've installed jdk version 8 and in cmd  java version "1.8.0_221" is coming. What does that mean?

Comment: It means you have JDK 8 installed

Comment: you are good, you have installed Java 8 and the _221 is just the update release(They keep on adding some features or there will be minor updates), for more info you can refer by clicking here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html

Comment: -version is useless: C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: My java -version shows java version ```"15.0.2" 2021-01-19```. How do I find out what my JDK is?

Comment: Important detail : it's -version not --version or -v

Answer (score 9):

You need to update your Windows `path` to include your `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` directory. `%JAVA_HOME%` is the directory that you installed Java into and is also an environment variable that you need to configure for command line execution of your applications. You can edit both of these in the Windows control panel and you should restart.

When you run `java -version` you will see the internal version number. This is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history.

Basically, you can ignore the `1.` when reading version number. The `_xxx` is a reference to the most recent patch or build release.

Comment: java version vs jdk versions could be different ? Seems useless or confusing at best ! JDK, JSE, it's all a bit bloody mess

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 10, this required mapping the environment variable for JAVA_HOME to the JDK installation directory. Use these steps:

0. Run the installer for the JDK. (available for windows here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows)
1. windows key -> `Environment Variables`, select the only result
2. In the System Properties window that opened, select `Environment Variables`
   [image]
3. Select `new` button under the `User variables` section
4. Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`, Variable Value: `<The JDK filepath from step 0>`
5. `ok` all open menus
6. Close any open cmd prompt windows
7. open a new cmd window and type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` It should print the installation path for the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

To get your jdk location in Windows, run this at a command prompt:

`where java`

This lists any and all locations of java.exe, including from your JAVA_HOME. For example, the 3rd line here reflects my JAVA_HOME location, where I'm pointing to JDK 8:

```
C:\Users\me> where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe
```

Note for comparison that `java -version` does **not** reflect my JAVA_HOME location and in fact shows java version 11 instead of 8:

```
C:\Users\me> java -version
java version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.15+8-LTS-149)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.15+8-LTS-149, mixed mode)
```

This is confusing because my Java compiles (e.g., via mvn) use JDK 8 since that's what my JAVA_HOME is pointing to. (I'm not even sure where the version 11 it found came from; possibly from when I installed maven.)

Determining the difference between the JRE and JDK you're running has never been straightforward. Seems like *java -version* used to be a way to do this, but no longer.

Adding to the complexity, you can [also](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.html) supposedly get your Java version info from **Control Panel** > **Programs** > **Java** > **About**. For me, that shows *Version 8*. That's despite *java -version* showing version *11.0.15*. And it doesn't change even if I point my JAVA_HOME to JDK 11.

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58721377/3368818) answer is also helpful. In my case, that helped me determine that I have java.exe and javac.exe at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` and `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`. For best results, it seems like you should delete these from your Path variable if you're using a non-Oracle version, such as openjdk.

Depending on which one I have listed first in my Path variable, I get different results when i run `java -version` or `java --version`. The former seems to work when Java 8 is listed first; the latter when Java 11 is first.